# Electron diffraction on crystal lattice

Tags: quantum-mechanics, diffraction

To observe electron diffraction, we standardly let its wavefunction pass trough a crystal lattice. However, why does not the electron's interaction with crystalline atoms cause wavefunction collapse?

Comment: Why should it? People seem to get hung up about wave functions collapsing, and then apply that everywhere...

Comment: @JonCuster I think that I understand your concern about wave function collapse but does not the lattice “detect” the electron and changes the wave function associated with the electron? So one wave function dies and another wave function is born? Is this a wrong way of interpreting the interaction between the lattice and an electron?

Comment: An electron propagating in vacuum has one wave function, but a free electron could be simply described as a plane wave. An electron propagating through a crystalline lattice is described using Bragg functions appropriate to the lattice. When the plane wave hits the lattice, the two sets of wave functions have to match up, allowing for transmission, reflection, refraction, and diffraction. No wave functions were collapsed during the making of this film...